# How do I expand div smoothly when new content is added

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How do I make a div expand smoothly when content is added?

```
const [render, setRender] = useState(false)

    const showHide= () => {
        setRender(!render)
    }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>TEST CONTAINER</h1>
      {render && <Paragprah />}
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={showHide}>Primary</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

In the above, a component is being rendered when a button is clicked, when the new content is added to the div, it expands instantly. basically, I would like it to expand smoothly when the content is added. Here is a video as well by what I mean when it expands instantly.

Setting a fixed height wont work in my situation because the content that's being loaded is dynamic, its coming from an API and the length is different everytime. So setting a fixed height will make the content overflow sometimes. I need a way where the transition can occur smoothly and the height still be large enough to fit the content, which would probably require ```height: auto;`` to be present?

[Link to Imgur video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BixyL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here I updated the code. Since the content that's being loaded has dynamic size then you have to track that content size using `useRef` hook and store it on a variable and export it with your component.

```
import { useRef, useEffect} from "react";

var ParagraphHeight;

function Paragraph() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    //when you content is loaded store its height
    ParagraphHeight = ref.current.offsetHeight;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <p>Your content here for exemple...</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export { Paragraph, ParagraphHeight };
```

Now import your Paragraph component and put it inside a `.wrapper` div that has a default height of 0px (that means your Paragraph will be hidden) and when you click on the button the height of it will change to the ParagraphHeight

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Paragraph, ParagraphHeight } from "./Paragraph.js";

export default function App() {
  const [isopned, setisopned] = useState(false);
  const [wrapperHeight, setWH] = useState(0);
  const showHide = () => {
    if (!isopned) setWH(ParagraphHeight);
    else setWH(0);
    setisopned(!isopned);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>TEST CONTAINER</h1>
      <div className="wrapper" style={{ height: wrapperHeight }}>
        <Paragraph />
      </div>
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={showHide}>
        Primary
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Finally don't forget to update your css, add overflow-y hidden and css transition to to expand your wrapper div smoothly.

```
.container {
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid; /*to prevent some problem caused by overflow hidden*/
  transition: height 1s linear;
  background-color: wheat;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

This is a live exemple [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-dust-7lwh1?file=/src/styles.css:0-213)

Comment: Ty, while this works, the specific problem that I'm facing is that the content that's being loaded is dynamic. As in it's coming from an API and it's different every time. So setting a fixed height will cause the content to overflow sometimes. I need a way where the transition can occur but still auto adjust the height to fit the content. I should probably rephrase the question

Comment: I updated the code, I hope it will be helpful, let me know if there is anything else. @devAR

Answer (score 0):

you can use the transition css property for a smooth transition.

```
transition: height 2s;
```

Follow [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1) for reference.